# PDF Files Compression Ghostscript

Tags: batch-file, ghostscript

Can someone check the code and find what is wrong ? I fight with it some time and don't have a clue whats wrong...
I get error:

```
'-sDEVICE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And this is my code:

```
@echo off

set "path=C:\cygwin64\bin;%path%"

rem directories to scan for files
set "filesDir[0]=.\MAGAZINES\"

rem extension of files to be scanned
set "ext=pdf"

rem file prefix for new files (if they should be created)
set "filepre="

rem loop over all directories defined in filesDir array
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('set filesDir[') do (
   if exist "%%~d" (
      pushd "%%~d"
      rem loop over all files in all (sub)directories with given extension
      for /f "delims=*" %%f in ('dir "*.%ext%" /b /s /a:-d') do (
            %ghostscript% -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="%TEMP%\%%~nxf" "%%~f"
            for %%t in ("%TEMP%\%%~nxf") do ( set "newSize=%%~zt" )
            for %%t in ("%%~f") do ( set "oldSize=%%~zt" )
            if [!newSize!] LSS [!oldSize!] (
               rem new file is smaller --> overwrite
               move /y "%TEMP%\%%~nxf" "%%~f"
            ) else (
               rem new file is greater --> delete it of the temp dir
               del "%TEMP%\%%~nxf"
            )
         )
      popd
   )
)

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the environment variable "ghostscript" is not set.

Try the command

```
set ghostscript
```

in the CMD terminal and see what it says.

If it says "Environment variable ghostscript not defined", there's your problem. It should point to the ghostscript executable (including quotes if there are spaces in the path, as you use `%ghostscript%` unquoted in the script).

If the Ghostscript executable is in `%path%`, the `ghostscript` environment variable does not need to include the path, only the name of the executable. The name of the executable would be either GSWIN32C.EXE (32-bit version) or GSWIN64C.EXE (64-bit version).

If the Ghostscript executable is not in `%path%`, the `ghostscript` environment variable will need to include the path. On my computer the entire path is "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64.exe", so on my computer I would set the `ghostscript` environment variable to

```
 "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64.exe"
```

*including the quotes* to make your script work.

Of course the specific path and the name of the .exe depends on how you installed Ghostscript.